# POA rows remain after removing share in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have removed sharing from a record in CRM manually. It is not shared via cascading rule eather, but it remains in Principal Object Access table. As I can see, the script for controlling growth of POA, published by Microsoft, deletes only rows with object ids which er deleted from CRM, can't see logic which removes those unshared records.
Does anyone know if CRM contains logic for this at all? Has anyone had experience with deleting those rows despite of being unsupportet action?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you very much about how the POA table is populated or cleaned up, but I can tell you how to delete it:

http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2014/01/lessons-learned-deleting-312-million.html

Comment: Sorry for delay, and thanks for replay. My question is not how to delete rows in POA though.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing also present for some entities even you can't see it in UI. Implicit sharing is created during entities merge or for email activities when there are different users in to:, cc: fields, for workflow logs, process sessions, etc.
I wrote short article about it: http://tunnik.name/principalobjectaccess-table-clean-it-up-fast/
It has links to other articles which can help dig into that subject.